# Symfony, Sonata Admin datagrid OR filtering

Tags: symfony, datagrid, filtering, sonata-admin

I'm using Symfony 2 with Sonata Admin Bundle.

As far as i can see, Sonata Admin has only AND filtering on list action.

Use this as example:

**My entity : Prodotto**

```
/**
* Prodotto
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity
* @UniqueEntity("prodotto")
*/
class Prodotto extends DefaultEntity
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

//getters - setters Zone

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="prodotto", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $prodotto;


/**
 * @var \mybundle\Entity\Tipologia
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tipologia")
 */
private $tipologia;


/**
 * @var \mybundle\Entity\Brand
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand")
 *
 */
private $brand;


/**
 * @var \mybundle\Entity\Layout
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Layout")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="layout_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $layout;

/**
 * @var \mybundle\Entity\Carta
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Carta")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="carta_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $carta;

//[... many other fields omitted...]
//[... Getters and setters omitted (default get/set, no custom code) ...]
```

**My admin class: ProdottoAdmin** (please note that i copied only the configuration useful for this question, the class contains all the required configurations for all the actions)

```
/**
 * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
 */
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('prodotto')
        ->add('tipologia')
        ->add('brand')
        ->add('layout')
        ->add('misura')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param ListMapper $listMapper
 */
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('dataModifica','datetime',array('pattern' => 'dd/MM/yyyy','label'=>'Data'))
        ->add('tipologia')
        ->add('brand')
        ->add('layout')
        ->add('misura')
        ->add('Nome Prodotto', 'string', array('template' => 'mybundle:Admin:List/link_column_list_prodotto.html.twig'))

        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'show' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
                'delete' => array(),
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

**My Service Configuration (in services.yml):**

```
services:
  mybundle.admin.prodotto:
      class: mybundle\Admin\ProdottoAdmin
      arguments: [~, mybundle\Entity\Prodotto, mybundle:ProdottoAdmin]
      tags:
          - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Prodotti, label: Prodotti}
```

With this configuration, i actually got a fully functional data grid filter, as you can see from the picture(image added for better understanding of the problem):

[image: Sonata_admin_default_filtering]

But, the default Sonata Admin filtering expose only an AND filter, i can add ONE time all the property of the entity and make an AND filtering with them.
But, now i need to extend that functionality. 
I need to add an OR filter, app-wide. I want that the user can filter like "give me all the product that are related with Brand1 OR Brand2 AND are of Tipologia1."

I know i can make precise custom query, like the example above, to obtain a single result, but:

1. That's will not be app-wide, i have many entities and i can't write all the custom query needed
2. That's verbose, i will have to write much of the same code in all the data grid filters
3. That's not wise, because if tomorrow i change an entity, the data grid filter is coupled with the entity and i need to remember to add/modify the query.

So, finally, my question is:

There is a "correct" (or at least, a raccomended)  way or pattern / maybe a configurable bundle to implement that OR filtering?

Comment: Have you gotten any solution to your problem ? Because im facing the same thing. Thank you.